# How to install plugins mentioned in the pom file from command line, without compiling or building the whole project?

Tags: java, maven

I have pom.xml file. I want to install the plugins mentioned in the pom file, without installing any other package or compile the project.

Is there a way to achieve this. I am trying to this to optimise docker build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try command mvn dependency:go-offline 
It will download your all dependencies and plugins